# Parsing an enum with the Flags attrubute not giving expected value

Tags: c#, parsing, enums, bitwise-operators

My enum:

```
        [Flags]
        public enum EqualityOperator
        {
            Equal,
            NotEqual,
            LessThan,
            LessThanOrEqual,
            GreaterThan,
            GreaterThanOrEqual,
            Like,
            NotLike,
            In,
            NotIn
        }
```

My code for parsing it:

```
var operatorVal = (EqualityOperator)Enum.Parse(typeof (EqualityOperator), filterInfo[3]);
```

When I debug, I can see that `filterInfo[3]` is `"Like"`

However, `operatorVal` comes out as `"LessThan | GreaterThan"`

What am I missing? Can you not parse enums with the Flags attribute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to also specify the values:

```
[Flags]
public enum EqualityOperator {
    Equal = 0,
    NotEqual = 1,
    LessThan = 2,
    LessThanOrEqual = 4,
    GreaterThan = 8,
    GreaterThanOrEqual = 16,
    Like = 32,
    NotLike = 64,
    In = 128,
    NotIn = 256
 }
```

The reason that `Like` is parsing as `LessThan | GreaterThan` is because as you've defined it, `LessThan` has value 2 and `GreaterThan` has value 4. If you take the bitwise-or of these, you end up with `LessThan | GreaterThan = 6`. But look, `Like` has the value `6` as you've defined your enum! So, it did parse "correctly".

I'll be frank with you though, I don't see the point of marking this enum with `Flags` though. The point of `Flags` is so that you can do bitwise operations on the enum values. Why do you think you need to do bitwise operations on the values of this enum?

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. To be honest, I don't see the point of marking the enum with [Flags] either. When I said my enum, I mean an enum in the system I'm extending that has > 150 usages so I didn't want to just remove [Flags] in case it was needed!

Answer (score 1):

In your case: 
`GreaterThan` equal 6. 
`LessThan` equal 2 and 
`GreaterThan` 4.

Therefore: GreaterThan = 6 = 110b = 2 + 4 = LessThan + GreaterThan.